# How can I set ENV variable in terminal before I run the meteor command?

Tags: meteor, configuration, environment-variables, mailer

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.startup(function() {
    return Meteor.Mandrill.config({
        username: USERNAME_MAIL,
        key: KEY_MAIL
    });
});

}
```

And I would like to set the USERNAME_MAIL and KEY_MAIL variable before running the server or to a deploy meteor app. How can this be done ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

you can either do it directly in front of the `meteor` command

```
USERNAME_MAIL="xxx" meteor
```

or `export` them just like any other ENV var and then fire up meteor

```
export USERNAME_MAIL="xxx"
export KEY_MAIL="yyy"
meteor // start meteor
```

see also this [meteorpedia](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables) article.

Comment: What I want is to know how to set the variables value before running the meteor command ? How do you set the ENV var from the terminal ?

Comment: When I do `USERNAME_MAIL="xxx" meteor` the terminal opens this `>`

Comment: have you tried the `export USERNAME_MAIL="xxx"`? check that the variable is defined using the command `env`. after that start meteor as usual typing `meteor`. works now?

Comment: what shell are you using? fish for example doesn't know `export` but uses the command `set` instead. there you also need to do `env USERNAME="xxx" meteor`. any luck?

Comment: when I do env USERNAME="xxx" meteor it does the same as doing it without the env. I am using the terminal from my mac. Terminal Version 2.5.3 (343.7)